# Can`t use Entity Framework - connection string not found

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I am using VS2012 with .NET 4.5. I am learning Entity Framework and I have a problem. I added ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project and generated my entities using the wizard.

The wizard added a connection string into `app.config` file :

```
<add name="MalariaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MalariaEntities.csdl|res://*/MalariaEntities.ssdl|res://*/MalariaEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OFIR-PC;initial catalog=Malaria;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In my project I am seeing all the entities and it seems fine but when I try to do any database action I get the following error:

> *No connection string named 'MalariaEntities' could be found in the application config file.*

For example, I tried to insert simple row:

```
using (MalariaEntities DB_Context = new MalariaEntities())
{
    MapsMainCategoriesDsc a = new MapsMainCategoriesDsc();
    a.Category = "aa";
    DB_Context.MapsMainCategoriesDsc.Add(a);
    DB_Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the debugger reach to the last line the exception is raised. What can be the problem?

The wizard added a connection string so why my project cannot use it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have separated project for DataAccess or EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes,  my Dal and entity framework sits together in same project but saperatly from my other modules

Comment: okay, in your module from entity framework, just copy and paste the connection string to your main project in app.config.

Comment: Thanks  - it really was my problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait! which config file? (Entity Framework Connection String)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223223/wait-which-config-file-entity-framework-connection-string)